# Numbers which constitute the Maximum sum

Tags: java, algorithm, java-8

I just wrote my program which finds the maximum sum from the array,
but I am stuck in is there any way by which I can find which numbers contributed to the max sum?

> Rule of Maximum sum is given: No adjacent elements should contribute
>   to sum.

My solution to maximum sum in array:

```
public class MaximumELementInARray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] al = reader.nextLine().split(" ");
        int[] input = Arrays.stream(al).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
        MaximumELementInARray mm = new MaximumELementInARray();
        int maxi = mm.maximumm(input);
        System.out.println(maxi);
    }

    public int maximumm(int[] a) {
        List<Integer> ex = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> inc = new ArrayList<>();
        int incl = a[0];
        int excl = 0;
        int excl_new;
        for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
            excl_new = Math.max(incl, excl);
            incl = excl + a[i];
            excl = excl_new;
        }
        System.out.println(incl > excl ? inc : ex);
        return incl > excl ? incl : excl;
    }
}
```

Now in the `maximum` function is there a tweak where I can put all the index of elements which constituted to the maximum sum?

Input:

-1 7 8 -5 4 9 -2 3

Output:

20

**

I require how 20 was arrived at. The answer should say `8+9+3`

**

I believe that in maximum function we could put an Arraylist and record which which elements are contributing to sum, but I am not able to implement.

I have made two Arraylist :

```
List<Integer> ex = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> inc = new ArrayList<>();
```

---

Input: -1 7 8 -5 4
Output: 12
The Sum is made up of 8+4

---

Input: 3 2 1 -1
Output: 4
The sum is made up of 3+1

etc....

Comment: Sir, *maximum sum is calculated on the rule that there should be no adjacent elements in the sum.*

Comment: What is max sum in your case? Don't you mean a subset with largest sum? For your example that would be `7+8+(-5)+4+9`?

Comment: Sir the  maximum sum is correct, is there anyway in which i can tag which which elements have contributed to max sum in my case?

Comment: You're trying to solve a task of finding subset summing to a given number, which is NP-complete in general case and usually solved by dynamic programming. A better solution will be modifying  `MaximumELementInARray.maximum` method to return not only resulting sum itself, but also augends that forms it.

Comment: @AlexSalauyou , i would love the solution and the approach.

Comment: When i am making the sum, is there No way by which i can tag elements that have constituted to the sum?

Comment: To "tag" items, operate indexes, not items themselves

Comment: @AlexSalauyou He is trying to find maximum sum by summing non-adjacent elements in the array.

Comment: @StevoMitric The question have been edited after I posted that comment

Comment: @JoakimDanielson , i don't think there is any limitation in java version, i am simply not able to get the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this code.

```
    int toIndex = 3, fromIndex = 0;
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    while (toIndex < numbers.size()) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = IntStream
                .range(fromIndex, toIndex)
                .filter(i->numbers.get(i)>0)
                .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(i, numbers.get(i)))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey,(a,b)->b));
        // find max of sublist
        int maxOfSub = numbers.subList(fromIndex, toIndex).stream().max(Integer::compareTo).get();
        //update indexes
        fromIndex = map.getOrDefault(maxOfSub,toIndex-1) + 2;
        toIndex += fromIndex;

        if (maxOfSub > 0)
            result.add(maxOfSub);
    }
    int lastMax = numbers.subList(fromIndex, numbers.size()).stream().max(Integer::compareTo).get();
    if (lastMax > 0)
        result.add(lastMax);
    System.out.println(result);
    System.out.println(result.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum));
```

***[DEMO](https://ideone.com/EueUM1)***

Comment: @tromu added demo to answer.

Comment: Hey thanks, but the output is just 20, it does not print which numbers constituted to 20 , the answer should be 8,9,3 not 20.

Comment: Moreover your program gives  9 as sum for `5 10 4 -1` , the max sum should be 10. :(

Comment: Wow, all cases are covered, but the least 1 is not getting passed. `4 5 4 3` , should give either [4,4] or [5,3] but i am getting **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key 0** , anyway to resolve this scenario? thank you man very much.

Comment: what if i want to get  `4 4` as the output as `4 4` also constitute to sum 8 , what should i do then?

Comment: well, I think you should check it at first. i.e `if (numbers.size()<toIndex) {
            result = numbers.stream().filter(num -> num > 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
        } else{....}`

Comment: @tromu see updated answer for duplicate key in map. `toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey,(a,b)->b))`

Comment: i have seen it. I am getting the result for `4 5 4 3` as 53 , but i need 44 in this case.